# eslint allowing duplicate const values

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

For some reason, this isn't yelling that I'm not allowed to do this. Does anyone know what I can add to my linter to make this invalid?

It's really causing issues because if I end up doing something like `duplicateName = duplicateName`, it obviously doesn't work.

```
const duplicateName = "Hi";

if(1 == 1) {
    const duplicateName = "Hey" 
}
```

### ES LINT

```
{
  "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "node": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
      "indent": [
          "error",
          "tab"
      ],
      "linebreak-style": [
          "error",
          "unix"
      ],
      "quotes": [
          "error",
          "single"
      ],
      "semi": [
          "error",
          "always"
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `const` declarations are block scoped.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes I know, is there a way to block this though in eslint?

Comment: so you want to ban shadowing? That's reasonable

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry, i didn't know what it was called but that seems like what I am trying to do.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow